# Observing [PHAsset] changes in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am customizing the album, browse all the photos, I got the following array collection.

`@Published var assetList: [PHAsset] = []`

Now I want to add a state that a photo is selected, how to add a selected parameter?

I tried extending `PHAsset`, but that didn't work

```swift
extension PHAsset {

    var selected: Bool? {
        get {
            return getAssociated(associatedKey: &AssociatedKeys.selected)
        }
        set {
            setAssociated(value: newValue, associatedKey: &AssociatedKeys.selected)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this simple alternative approach, using a new `struct` to hold the `PHAsset` and the `isSelected` bool.

```
struct MyAsset: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var phAsset: PHAsset
    var isSelected: Bool
}
```

and have:

```
   @Published var assetList: [MyAsset] = []
```